# Magento 2: location for custom templates in custom theme

Tags: magento2, theme, custom-theme

I have a question about how to organize a custom theme. I am planning to build a new theme that does not extend the blank theme. I am building my own blank theme so to speak.

I get the idea that modules template files reside in their respective folder inside my theme folder, e.g. Magento_Catalog/ and so on.

But my custom theme needs more template files that have no module to derive from. Where would I put those files?

Is Magento_Theme actually a custom theme's first point of entry?

Comment: which types of templates and from where you want to call this files (like from cms page, block, layout..)

Comment: E.g. default.xml. First off I want to implement some global containers, blocks and corresponding template files.  I guess what I am looking for is the m2 equivalence of the local.xml in m1.